# css, js files are not being pointed in angular2

Tags: angular

> Explanation of what i am doing: I am making an HTML editor, now in order to edit a section[example about us, features,benefits] i need to load all the css,js of my template inside the editor, for this purpose i need to call external css,js files. These files has no relation with my editor, but in order to load my section properly i need to call these files. Hope you are clear on my requirement

I am trying to make a simple view.html page in my angular2 project.

On my view.component.html i am inserting HTML data in 2 steps: 
**Step1:** i am loading the html skeleton structure like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    // insert the template skeleton code 
this.get_template_skeleton  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("templateType"));
console.log(this.get_template_skeleton.template_code);
this.document.body.innerHTML += this.get_template_skeleton.template_code;
```

template body look something like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sources/template/css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body id="page-top">
    <div id="main-wrapper">
{{CONTENT}}
    </div>
 <script src="sources/template/js/count.js"></script>
    <script src="sources/template/js/menu.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Step 2:** I am inserting html data in `<div id="main-wrapper">` like this:

```
this.document.getElementById("main-wrapper").innerHTML = this.section_desc;
```

> I have placed my css,js files like this - sources/template/css/ , sources/template/js/

**Where should i place my sources folder so that my files load**, they are not loading at the moment.

This is what i am seeing in the console, as css,js files not being called

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hd1rwvdwlugwzxz/Screenshot%202017-05-29%2014.05.54.png?dl=0

Comment: The real question is _why_ you would want to do that as oppose to use built-in directives such as 'ngIf' or 'ngSwitch'? Maybe I misunderstood, is your question how to use components?

Comment: I am making an HTML editor, now in order to edit a section i need to load all the css,js of my template inside the editor, for this purpose i need to call external css,js files. These files has no relation with my editor, but in order to load my section properly i need to call these files. Hope you are clear on my requirement

Answer (score 0):

if your are using angular-cli to develop your project you need to add your custom styles into the **.angular-cli.json** file:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    // location-to-your-custom-styling-file
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular.json

```
  "styles": [
    "src/assets/scss/styles.scss"
    // you can add your external style here 
            ],
  "scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    // you can add your external style here 
  ]
```